# How to randomly access a text file in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, unix

I have a big log file in which the records are sorted by time. Each line has a time. I need to find all the records between time T1 and time T2 (T1 <= T2). I can scan the whole file line by line and find the start line with T1, copy that into a buffer and then scan the next line until I hit the end time T2. This will work but not very efficient.

I wonder if I can use binary search to locate the lines with time T1 and T2. But I am not sure how to determine the following:

1. The middle line of the file
2. How to determine the offset we should pass to `lseek()`?

Is that possible to use binary search on a file?

Comment: Are "lines" fixed width, or do they vary?

Comment: @TomKerr Most logs will contain variable length lines and if the lines were fixed width, then the question would be quite trivial.

Comment: @Nobody He didn't specify.  Turns out communicating requirements is a large part of software design.

Comment: @TomKerr I agree with you on that. The information should be given but for now we could assume the worse to get working, as there are no million $ contracts that could be broken when we misunderstand something :)

Comment: I assumed he was doing looking at binary files for some reason, which is wrong.

Comment: @TomKerr The lines are not necessarily same in length. But what can we do if the lines are fixed length? We can go from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume, that your lines are all reasonable near to the average length (meaning there is no line that will take up half of the log or so), which will make binary search feasible.

Next I will also assume you will have following functions:

```
//find the first start of a new log line after (or including) position start
//return the last position of the file if no start could be found
streampos findNextLineStart(ifstream &file, streampos start);
//extract the data as a timestamp from a line
int extractDate(ifstream &file, streampos lineStart);
```

With these functions we can implement the following:

```
//find the position of the first line whose date is bigger than the given
streampos lower_bound(ifstream &file, int date)
{
  file.seekg(0, ios::end);
  streampos begin = 0, 
            end = file.tellg();
  while(begin < end)
  {
     streampos cur = (begin + end) / 2;
     streampos start = findNextLineStart(file, cur);
     //was a line start found?
     if(start < end)
     {
        int lineDate = extractDate(file, start);
        if(lineDate < date)
          begin = start;
        else
          end = start;
     }
     else
       //narrow the bound as no line was found
       end = cur;
  }
  return begin;
}
```

I do not guarantee for this to work (on all corner cases) but it sketches the overall implementation. One would use another function `upper_bound` and with those you could get start and end of the lines that are within your bounds.

Comment: Thank you. So you get the file size by ifstream::tellg(), and find the position of middle point of the file. Then findNextLineStart() will find the next line after the middle point. Can you suggest how I implement this function?

Comment: The most obvious solution that pops to my mind is to walk on from the current position to the next newline character, which will denote the next line and return the position next after this. I think it would be wise to do a check if the current position is already the start of a line (it is the first position in the file or the previous character is a new line). If you do not encounter a new line until the end you return the sentinel value (the size of the file/the offset one past the last byte).

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough address space, consider using memory-mapped files. They tend to be one of the easiest and most efficient ways of doing this. Use boost::iostreams::mapped_file for portability.

Comment: When using memory-mapped file is the entire file going to be loaded into memory? If this is the case, this may not be desirable.

Comment: @itnovice, no, the entire file is mapped into virtual memory but the OS only loads pieces of the file into physical memory as needed. On 32-bit platforms there is some concern about running out of virtual memory space since there is only a few GB of address space available but this approach won't use up extra physical memory. On 64-bit platforms, it's fine to memory map files much larger than the amount of physical memory available.

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably don't want to do a binary search to find the last record in the range. Once you find T1 you read records linearly until you find one outside the desired range anyway, so you really only need to find the first record in the range.

Also, you don't really need to implement the binary search by finding the exact n/2-th record. If you simply seek to the byte halfway between your two current boundaries, find the next full record and update your boundaries from that, then that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the middle line.  Instead you can take the middle **character** and then move backwards one character at a time until you have found a newline; then you know you have the start of the current line.  If that line has a timestamp which is too far in the future, then you can discard that line and everything after it.  If its timestamp is too far in the past, discard it and everything before it.  You can repeat this until you've found the line(s) you want.

This is the standard binary search algorithm.  You do not really need the middle line in binary search - it is sufficient to have something that is approximately the middle.  It might be slow in some extreme cases where some lines are **much** longer than others, but generally it'll be fast enough.